# Value not selected in dropdown, why?

Tags: react-native, dropdown

I am using react native material ui  component to select value and 
  set it. But selected value does not stay on the screen. Cannot see the 
   selected value. Why so?

```
 ` 

    onChangeHandler = (e) => {
    this.setState({
    selectValue: e
    });
  }
      render() {
      sports = [
      { value:'Basketball' },
      { value:'Football' },
      { value:'Tennis' },
      { value:'Volleyball' }
      ];
       <Dropdown
             value={this.state.selectValue} 
             data = {sports}
             style={styles.Dropdown1}
             onChangeText = {(event) => this.onChangeHandler(event)}
            ><Dropdown>
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to `console.log()` the event you are passing, and see what is raised in that event

I would try something like the following:

```
    onChangeHandler = (evt) => {
    this.setState({
    selectValue: evt.target.value
    });
  }
      render() {
      sports = [
      { value:'Basketball' },
      { value:'Football' },
      { value:'Tennis' },
      { value:'Volleyball' }
      ];
       <Dropdown
             value={this.state.selectValue} 
             data = {sports}
             style={styles.Dropdown1}
             onChangeText = {this.onChangeHandler}
            ><Dropdown>
 }
```